# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'photos' of undefined

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
$.each(variant['photos'], function( index, object ) {
            object['idx'] = index;
            if(index == 0) object['active'] = true;
        });
```

produces following error:

> error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'photos' of undefined

[image]

Comment: let the community know what you want to achieve at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that error message is pretty self explanatory. You are attempting to read a property of something that isn't defined. In this case, the error comes from `variant['photos']`. You haven't defined `variant`.